# How to use angular-charts with json data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, charts

Im trying to visualise some data with [angular-charts](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) but I don't know what am I doing wrong. I'm a beginner in angularjs.

Data should be passed this way:

```
  $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
```

I am using $http to get it from API so I have sth like this:

```
app.controller("LineCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/meteo_dane'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.dane = response.data;
        $scope.labels = [$scope.dane.updated_at];
        $scope.series = ['Series A'];
        $scope.data = [
            [$scope.dane.temp],
        ];
        console.log(this.dane);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        //
    });
```

But its now working - chart is empty.
Data that I am going to use is in this format:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "567aa394d452128c6d595f0e",
    "windspeedmph": 0,
    "winddir": 135,
    "humidity": 30.5,
    "temp": 24,
    "updated_at": "2015-12-23T13:37:24.881Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "567aa39ed452128c6d595f0f",
    "windspeedmph": 0,
    "winddir": 135,
    "humidity": 30.4,
    "temp": 24.1,
    "updated_at": "2015-12-23T13:37:34.836Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
]
```

I am going to show temperature in time. Later I would like to show the rest of data that I have.

How should I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you `$scope.data` assignment has wrong format, it should have multidimensional array.

You should create array of `$scope.temp` which will have `temp` for each `dane`

```
$scope.temp = [] 
angular.forEach($scope.dane, function(value){
   $scope.temp.push(value.temp)
});
$scope.data = $scope.temp //removed [] because its already an array.
```

[**Example Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/o6nSTD5tPRTRuOLgPXck?p=preview)

Comment: Do you mean sth like this:
`$scope.dane = response.data;
        $scope.temp = [];
        $scope.updated_at = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.dane, function(value){
            $scope.temp.push(value.temp);
            $scope.updated_at.push(value.updated_at);
        });
        $scope.labels = $scope.dane.updated_at;
        $scope.series = ['Series A'];
        $scope.data = $scope.updated_at;`

Comment: @wiwo take a look at the sample plunkr which I have added.

Comment: That was it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @wiwo Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: I've seen that you know a lot about AngularJS and Chart.js. I did use a few of your answers to others questions. Could you please take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516923/angular-chartjs-how-to-make-it-reactive-to-data-change